# How to differentiate between "shapes" when given parametric equations?

Tags: calculus, functions

Having a hard time understanding how to figure out how a function looks like when it's in parametric form.

Here are two examples, just wondering if someone could help me develop some sort of intuition as to how to look at it.

\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh s \\
t+\cosh s \\
3+2t \\
\end{pmatrix}

and

\begin{pmatrix}
2e^ {-t} \\
3+e^t \\
3+2t \\
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Do you mean $\cosh s$? If so, that is acquired by writing `\cosh s` rather than `coshs`. Also, the way to get exponents with more than one symbol in them is to put curly braces around them, so in order to get $e^{-t}$, you need to write `e^{-t}`.

Comment: Thank you @Arthur! Need to get my mathjax game up to par

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first vector function has two parameters, $s$ and $t$. Therefore the graph of that function is a surface with two dimensions. It may be curved, but it will look like a (perhaps twisted) sheet.

To think better how the surface will look, not that the parameter $s$ appears only in the expression $\cosh s$. We can replace that expression with parameter $u$, remembering that since $u=\cosh s$ it will take the values $1\le u$. We then get

$$\begin{pmatrix} u \\t+u \\3+2t \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}+
t\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}+
(u-1)\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Either expression shows that the surface is (part of) a plane and that the point $(1,1,3)$ is on the surface. Since $u$ is limited, that means the surface is a half-plane, and $(1,1,3)$ is on the edge of the plane.

That probably is enough for intuition: playing with the expression just a little shows that we have a half-plane. Here is the graph:

[image]

Your second vector function has only one parameter, $t$. That means it is a curve in space, with one dimension. It will look like a (perhaps twisted) line.

To see what kind of curve, we see that removing the constant term $(0,3,3)$ from the function, the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are near-reciprocals of each other. Actually, we would get $xy=2$. The graph of that curve in the $xy$ plane is a hyperbola, but since both $x$ and $y$ must be positive we would get only one branch of the hyperbola.

The $z$ linear term means the hyperbola branch is turned out of the $xy$ plane, and the constant $(0,3,3)$ means the hyperbola apparently does not have its center at the origin. Again, by playing with the expression a little we figure out its basic shape. Here is its graph:

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! Guess it will just take much more practice to be able to see these things without the help of a graphing calculator.

By the way, what program do you use to graph? I would love to have something like that that graphs parameterized functions!

Comment: @RonaldB: I used the TI-Nspire CX Teacher software. The parts I used here just emulate the TI-Nspire CX calculator. I also have Sage software, but I'm not comfortable doing 3D graphing with it yet. I should emphasize that I did my exploration of the graph shapes *before* doing the graphing. The only thing I learned from the graphs was that the second graph still is a hyperbola branch after the "stretching" of the $z$ coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

In 3 space ( 3 coordinates) if there is *one*  independent parameter it is some *curved line*. If there are *two* independent parameters, then the two curved line mesh together making up a *surface*. The plot in either case is parametric in 2D and 3D.